# Undefined variable in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Sorry for broken english,
I am use domcrawler to extract element from web page, and i try to show it in views, but i getting error like this :

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined variable: judul
in Webscrapper.php (line 30)
```

code :

```
$crawler->filter('td.gsc_a_t > a')->each(function ($node) 
{
   $judul[]=$node->text();
});
return view('scrape',['judul' => $judul]);
```

line 30 is :

```
 return view('scrape',['judul' => $judul]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$judul = $crawler->filter('td.gsc_a_t > a')->each(function ($node, $index) {
    return $node->text(); 
});

return view('scrape',['judul' => $judul]);
```

In your code, the `$judul[]` is defined inside a closure (anonymous function) so outside the closure that variable is not available. Check more on [symfony website](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values).